# FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan when using greater int values

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I've recently watched a YouTube (DataSchool) video where the guy used only 3 columns from the Titanic dataset and made a pipeline. I wanted to add more columns to get better accuracy so I added Age and Fare.

[image: DataFrame]

I think it's probably because of the values of `Age` and `Fare` that I'm getting this error when I perform `cross_val_score`

```
columns_trans = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(), ['Sex', 'Embarked']),
    remainder='passthrough')
logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')

pipe = make_pipeline(columns_trans, logreg)

cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy').mean()
```

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:552: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan.

If I remove `Age` and `Fare`, everything works fine. I was wondering if the `Column Transformer` or the `make_pipeline` had a problem with values like that.

I also tried scaling the values of Fare and Age, then it gave a `cross_val_score` but failed in `pipe.predict()` giving an error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

**Traceback**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_119/4279568460.py in <module>
----> 1 cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy', error_score="raise").mean()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    404                                 fit_params=fit_params,
    405                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch,
--> 406                                 error_score=error_score)
    407     return cv_results['test_score']
    408 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    246             return_times=True, return_estimator=return_estimator,
    247             error_score=error_score)
--> 248         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    249 
    250     zipped_scores = list(zip(*scores))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1039             # remaining jobs.
   1040             self._iterating = False
-> 1041             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1042                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1043 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    857                 return False
    858             else:
--> 859                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    860                 return True
    861 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    775         with self._lock:
    776             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 777             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    778             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    779             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 
    265     def __reduce__(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 
    265     def __reduce__(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    529             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    530         else:
--> 531             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    532 
    533     except Exception as e:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    333             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
    334                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 335                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    336 
    337         return self

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1415                       penalty=penalty, max_squared_sum=max_squared_sum,
   1416                       sample_weight=sample_weight)
-> 1417             for class_, warm_start_coef_ in zip(classes_, warm_start_coef))
   1418 
   1419         fold_coefs_, _, n_iter_ = zip(*fold_coefs_)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1039             # remaining jobs.
   1040             self._iterating = False
-> 1041             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1042                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1043 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    857                 return False
    858             else:
--> 859                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    860                 return True
    861 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    775         with self._lock:
    776             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 777             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    778             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    779             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 
    265     def __reduce__(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 
    265     def __reduce__(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py in _logistic_regression_path(X, y, pos_class, Cs, fit_intercept, max_iter, tol, verbose, solver, coef, class_weight, dual, penalty, intercept_scaling, multi_class, random_state, check_input, max_squared_sum, sample_weight, l1_ratio)
    762             n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
    763                 solver, opt_res, max_iter,
--> 764                 extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
    765             w0, loss = opt_res.x, opt_res.fun
    766         elif solver == 'newton-cg':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/optimize.py in _check_optimize_result(solver, result, max_iter, extra_warning_msg)
    241                 "    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/"
    242                 "preprocessing.html"
--> 243             ).format(solver, result.status, result.message.decode("latin1"))
    244             if extra_warning_msg is not None:
    245                 warning_msg += "\n" + extra_warning_msg

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Set `error_score="raise"` in `cross_val_score` to get the full error traceback (instead of having `cross_val_score` mask the error and just give score NaN).  The titanic dataset (as provided by sklearn's `fetch_openml`, with `version=1`) does have missing values in age, and one(??) in fare, so you'll need to deal with those.

Comment: @BenReiniger The extended error message says `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` but there are no strings and no missing values present in the columns.

Comment: Put the whole traceback into the question, please.

Comment: @BenReiniger Added it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by changing `solver=lbfgs` to `solver=liblinear` in `LogisticRegression()`

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
```

to

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
```

And for the following error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

It's best to check if your `test` data contains any null values or strings.